# Permissibility Of Wearing Jordan Brand

Tags: clothing

I have a question regarding the Jordan brand, is it permissible to wear as it’s produced by Nike? I understand that Nike is a brand that promotes Greek Mythology but Jordan has no association with the mythology other then it being owned by Nike, hypothetically if a Muslim wears Jordan is he promoting Nike? The Greek mythology company? And also In the inner shoe the word Nike is wrote, to show it is made by Nike, would it be permissible to wear? Or would i have to remove the Nike lettering?